# How do I set my web server to run as a specific user other than 'nobody'?

Tags: apache-2.2, user-accounts, user-permissions, user-profile

This is for an unremarkable LAMP server running Ubuntu. The reason I want to do this is because I want a php script to be able to run a linux command via the exec() function and the command I want to run needs permission that 'nobody' does not have.I have added my new user 'web' with the appropriate permissions, now I just need my web server to be the user 'web'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is located in:

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

And is usually (by default):

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

You can change the user that apache runs as here. You'll need to restart apache for the changes to take.

**What you really want is SUEXEC.**
What you're proposing is rather quick and dirty; it also poses a huge security risk.

What you should really be doing is [this](http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=2982).

Comment: I wish "What you really want is SUEXEC." could be bigger and bolder! Exactly what I needed. Didn't see it at first.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html).  Alternately you can set the user Apache runs as.  This is an excerpt from my httpd.conf

```
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User www
Group www
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is coming late, but i stumbled upon this question when i was trying to solve a similar problem. I would suggest you run **WHOIAM** to determine the current user. Then grant the user the right permission using **VISUDO**

By default apache runs with the user www-data you can apply the permission in **visudo** by including the following line in **/etc/sudoers**

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/local/bin
```

you can replace **/usr/local/bin** with the command you want to run in your script.