# Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (XX) of file

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, suphp

I'm kind of a server noob.

I'm just running httpd server which uses `Nobody` as the owner of the processes. My php files are `chmod` as `755` with ownership as `Apache:Apache`.

It triggers this error `Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (XX) of file "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/index2.php"`

I reckon I have to

- change owners (or group?) of my php scripts to Nobody or
- make [httpd run its processes as Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/298677/how-do-i-set-my-web-server-to-run-as-a-specific-user-other-than-nobody) (for which I can't find `/etc/httpd/envvars`)
- something else entirely?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to run Apache as user wwww-data (or web or www, depending on the distribution), and likely the user Apache in your case, so I would use the second option.

What distribution are you using? Beside the `envvars` method, you can specify the [user](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user) in Apache's config files as well.

Comment: If that's the case, any idea why I couldn't find /etc/httpd/envvars as the linked answer says?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: it's using

`Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) | 

Server built:   Nov 23 2011 17:37:00 | 

Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.7.1 rev9999`